# Word Choice/Phrase: Alternate Term for “Little Opportunity”

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking to use another word in place of "little opportunity," but can't seem to think of one. Any suggestions?

They left the country to escape the little opportunity.

Comment: How about scarcity, little prospects, meagreness?

Comment: "escape the little opportunity" is awkward. *"Finding it a place of little opportunity, they left the country"* OR *"The country offered (them) no prospect of work/success/... and they left"* might be better.

Comment: “escape the little opportunity” is not English.

Comment: @Trusha_Patel: We *might* "escape the scarcity **of**" something, or the "meagreness **of the**" something, but we don't "escape the little prospects".

Answer (score 1):

I would escape the lack of opportunities.

"They left the country to escape the lack of opportunities."

Answer (score 0):

"They left the country to escape the **scant** opportunity (ies).

Google search: Scant - barely sufficient or adequate, as in "companies with scant [little] regard for the safety of future generations"

Middle English as a noun, "scant supply, scarcity," from Old Norse. As a verb and adverb from mid-15c (https://www.etymonline.com/word/scant).

You use scant to indicate that there is very little of something or not as much of something as there should be.  She began to berate the police for paying scant attention to the theft from her car.  If you describe an amount as scant, you are emphasizing that it is small (https://dictionary.reverso.net/english-cobuild/scant+opportunities).

Answer (score 0):

We can use **only a little opportunity** in place of 'little opportunity'.

only a little= little

Little is negative. It has a negative idea. Little means 'not much'.

Little opportunity= not much opportunity, not enough opportunity

We can also use **little chance**, **not much opportunity**, **not enough opportunity** etc.